# File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 29, in <module> import debconf

Tags: dpkg

So, I'm trying to install the Flash player plugin, but it says update-notifier-common is not configured. So I do `sudo dpkg --configure update-notifier-common` and it displays

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 29, in <module>
  import debconf
ImportError: No module named debconf
dpkg: error processing update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
```

But `sudo apt-get install debconf` gives

```
Setting up update-notifier-common (0.147.1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/update-notifier/package-data-downloader", line 29, in <module>
    import debconf
ImportError: No module named debconf
dpkg: error processing update-notifier-common (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of flashplugin-installer:
 flashplugin-installer depends on update-notifier-common (>= 0.119ubuntu2); however:
  Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing flashplugin-installer (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
          Errors were encountered while processing:
 update-notifier-common
 flashplugin-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

So, it looks like I can't configure update-notifier-common until I've installed debconf, and I can't install debconf until I'll installed debconf and configured update-notifier-common. Help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resolve unmet dependencies?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies)

Comment: @Jobin not a dupe, check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your installation of debconf seems corrupt due the lack of the debconf library. If you don't get this:

```
$ ls -l /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/debconf.py*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   34 nov  3 14:20 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/debconf.py -> ../../../share/pyshared/debconf.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6013 dic  9 01:58 /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/debconf.pyc

$ ls -l /usr/share/pyshared/debconf.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 5971 nov  3 14:20 /usr/share/pyshared/debconf.py
```

Then you are in pretty screwed. You may try to repair it using:

```
mkdir -p ~/debconf.bk
sudo mv /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/debconf.pyc ~/debconf.bk
sudo mv /usr/share/pyshared/debconf.py ~/debconf.bk
apt-get download debconf
dpkg --extract debconf*.deb
sudo pycompile -p debconf
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Answer (score 0):

no need for the long process Braiam specified.

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall debconf
```

should get you going.

Comment: This causes the initial `Package update-notifier-common is not configured yet` to happen

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your `/usr/bin/python` to point to python version 2.7

Comment: Can you provide references or a convincing technical explanation ?